# Name a method using the value of a variable

Tags: java, naming

So say I had a variable like this:

```
String var = "name"
```

instead of making a method like so -

```
Public void name{
    System.out.println("This is a method called name");
}
```

I want to create like this -

```
Public void var{
    System.out.println("This is a method called name");
}
```

but instead of the method being called var, I want it to be called name

The reason I need this:

I'm building a lexer/parser, and this reads methods from another (made up) language, so I want to transfer these methods into java with the same names to be called upon later on

Comment: Tried to make something like this some time ago. Didn't find any way :/

Comment: @Jyr Basically, I'm building a lexer/parser, so I have methods from another language and want to transfer these to java with the same names

Comment: Why you need this ? You can use reflection or under Java 8 lambdas/functional references. Please provide more detail why you need this  ...

Comment: Your question smells of being a classic [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. I think  that you may be ascribing more power to method names than they really have.

Comment: @kulatamicuda I've added some explanation as to why I think I need this

Comment: @Summer I would use different approach. Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern , as Hovercraft  has written, your problem smels liike classic XY problem.

Comment: @kulatamicuda Interpreter pattern looks as though it will work from a glance, thank you!!

Comment: Nice work @kulatamicuda!